# jQuery-checked radio button doesn't get checked despite having "checked" attribute set to "checked"

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I manually checked a radio button using `.attr('checked', true);` (because `prop( 'checked', true);` didn't seem to do anything in my case).

Although the radio button does get a `checked` attribute equal to `checked` in the markup, the radio button still isn't checked (visually on the page, *all* radio buttons remain unchecked).

How is that even possible?

jQuery:

```
$( '.variations_fieldset input[value="Every 2 months"]' ).attr('checked', true);
```

HTML obtained:

```
<fieldset class="variations_fieldset">
    <input type="radio" data-attribute_name="attribute_billing" name="attribute_billing" id="billing1" value="Once Off">
    <label for="billing1">Once Off</label>
    <input type="radio" data-attribute_name="attribute_billing" name="attribute_billing" id="billing2" value="Every 1 month">
    <label for="billing2">Every 1 month</label>
    <input type="radio" data-attribute_name="attribute_billing" name="attribute_billing" id="billing3" value="Every 2 months" checked="checked">
    <label for="billing3">Every 2 months</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Comment: Are you using any plugin for radio button like css styling?

Comment: Yes, but can CSS prevent a radio button from looking checked even when it is indeed checked?

Comment: In your example you already have `checked="checked"` on the last input, but even without it the jQuery works: https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/e0tpgekm/

Comment: A property update doesn't actually add an attribute you can see - it changes an internal state, so `.prop("checked", true)` is the correct way to do it - you can look for the result with `$(":checked")`

Comment: Can you please provide full code/CSS/HTML? Perhaps a JSFiddle? So long as you use `prop` it appears to work just fine, so not sure where your problem is.

Comment: [No problems with `.prop` here](https://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/gateg0rw/)

Comment: @Blazemonger: Same result I had, but does not stop downvoters :) I think there may be more to this question not yet revealed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use `prop` to hit underlying properties of elements, not `attr`:

```
$( '.variations_fieldset input[value="Every 2 months"]' ).prop('checked', true);
```

`attr` just changes the DOM but does not always set the underlying property.

Please note: `prop` does not update the `attr`, so you can't see the change in the DOM inspector.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/e0tpgekm/1/

Comment: A property change doesn't add a "checked" attribute to the radio button.

Comment: @shawnt00: OP may have not realised that a `attr` change would not be visible in the DOM if you use prop. You cannot always take statements like that at face value.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I'm not downvoter. OP says it's not checked on the page. Is that what it's supposed to do?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "attr just changes the DOM but does not always set the underlying property."? Also, as you can see in the fiddle I posted in the comment above, the OP's code does check the proper radio button using attr() https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/e0tpgekm/

Comment: @j08691: On all browsers? :) I was taught it was always best to use `prop` for any properties that have side-effects (like checked). **Have requested more info from OP as they should not have a problem anyway (as you found).**

Comment: Oh I'm not disagreeing that .prop() should be used over attr() here, I'm just saying that given the code the OP posted that it works (in testing on Chrome and FF). And newer devs may now understand what you meant by "but does not always set the underlying property".

Comment: It worked but at the same time it didn't: now the radio button gets visually checked, but then upon submitting my form PHP doesn't see it as checked! I guess it's because prop() doesn't do anything with "checked" attribute. But then prop() is incomplete right? What's the point of checking a radio button visually if the code receiving submitted form doesn't see it?

Comment: `prop` *is* the only thing guaranteed to check it on all browsers. You have something else going on.

Comment: @drake035 Q: PHP should not see "checked"... Shouldn't it see a name-value pair with the selected value?

Answer (score -2):

If you are using jQuery prior to 1.6 try this:

```
.attr('checked','checked');
```